# Cholesky decomposition for symmetric positive semi-definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, positive-semidefinite, cholesky-decomposition

On page 5 here: https://stanford.edu/class/ee363/lectures/lmi-s-proc.pdf

[image]

$A$ and $B$ are decomposed into $A^{1/2} A^{1/2}$ and same for $B$.

Is this from Cholesky decomposition? Can someone prove that PSD symmetric matrices always admit this factorization?

Comment: Symmetric positive definite matrices always have a [Cholesky decompositon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition). The algorithm is so simple that you can easily see that it also works for symmetric positive *semi* definite matrices. The converse is trivial. ***Corollary***: *A matrix is symmetric PSD if and only if it has a Cholesky decomposition.*

Answer (score 2):

No, $A^{1/2}$ does not refer to the lower triangular matrix obtained from Cholesky decomposition. It is the unique positive semidefinite square root of $A$. That is, if $A=QDQ^T$ is an (Schur) orthogonal diagonalisation, then $A^{1/2}$ is defined as $QD^{1/2}Q^T$, where $D^{1/2}$ is the entrywise square root of $D$. It is evident that $A^{1/2}$ is positive semidefinite (and symmetric in particular) and $(A^{1/2})^2=A$.

The identity in question follows from the tracial property $\operatorname{tr}(XY)=\operatorname{tr}(YX)$:
\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{tr}(AB)
&=\operatorname{tr}(\underbrace{A^{1/2}}_X\,\underbrace{A^{1/2}B^{1/2}B^{1/2}}_Y)\\
&=\operatorname{tr}(\underbrace{A^{1/2}B^{1/2}B^{1/2}}_Y\,\underbrace{A^{1/2}}_X)\\
&=\operatorname{tr}\left((A^{1/2}B^{1/2})(A^{1/2}B^{1/2})^T\right)\\
&=\| A^{1/2}B^{1/2}\|_F^2.
\end{aligned}